# No wifi adapter found [dell precision 5530 & ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, network-interface, bluetooth

On my laptop I have trouble with wireless networking since I installed linux. Sometimes when I start the laptop (1 of 3 times) my wireless card doesn't work. Wifi option is missing when I click on toolbar, and in settings in wifi and bluetooth section I got the error:

> No adapter found

I also tried checking it with the command `sudo lshw -C network`
and there is no information about that wireless interface. When I turn off (restart doesn't cut it) and then on, everything works again. When I run the `lshw` command again, I can see this:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
   logical name: wlp59s0
   version: 32
   serial: d8:9c:67:b6:98:53
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-45-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.18 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:142 memory:ed200000-ed3fffff
```

I also tried updating the bios firmware to the newest version, but it doesn't work.

Edit: I added output from `dmesg` command after startup when wifi didn't work

[dmesg's output on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/nRi7BeLT)

Edit:
I can't boot system with working wifi anymore but I found this in output of dmesg command:

```
ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0
ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0
ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0
ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0
ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Failed to find firmware-N.bin (N between 2 and 6) from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0: -2
ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
MXM
ACPI Warning
ACPI Warning
pci 0000:01:00.0: optimus capabilities: enabled, status dynamic power, hda bios codec supported
VGA switcheroo: detected DSM method \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP handle
```

Comment: This looks like some failure to detect the hardware. Please look through `dmesg` after boot in one of those cases when Wifi doesn't work, possibly you can see errors.

Comment: @dirkt I eddited question and added output from dmesg uploaded to pastebin because of long text

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Your wireless adapter sits on PCI bus 3b. According to `dmesg`,

```
[    0.338888] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 3b]
```

this bus is behind PCI bridge `0:1c.0`. There are four error messages regarding four different PCI bridges:

```
[    0.888395] dpc 0000:00:1b.0:pcie010: DPC error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
[    0.888407] dpc 0000:00:1c.0:pcie010: DPC error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
[    0.888423] dpc 0000:00:1c.4:pcie010: DPC error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
[    0.888436] dpc 0000:00:1d.0:pcie010: DPC error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
```

so this might be why it can't find the wireless adapter. I don't know what's supposed to be behind those other bridges.

You could compare to a `dmesg` output from a working boot, see if the error messages are still present.

However, I suspect some kind of hardware problem. This won't be easy to fix.

Comment: I checked output of dmesg when system boot correctly, and that log contains these errors as well.

Comment: Can you upload that one too, so I can check for other differences?

Comment: unfortunatelly I cannot start system correctly but I found error message in log, chech please updated question

Comment: Ath10k firmware needs to be installed separately, see e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation), or google. If installing the firmware doesn't fix it: Can you consistently see 0000:3b:00.0 with `lspci`, or is it sometimes present, and sometimes not?

Comment: I installed firmware separately but doesn't help immediately. Wifi still working randomly. In case when wifi is working I have 3b:00.0 code with lspci, but when it isn't working I can't even see network in output list of lspci :/

Comment: If you can't see `3b:00.0` in `lspci`, this again points to a hardware fault when the PCI devices are not correctly enumerated, and your wifi hardware is just treated as not present. Can you open up the computer and reseat all connectors, if there are any?

Comment: so what is your advice? claim to laptop? or it's just linux thing?

Comment: It could be a PCI driver problem (see the error messages for the bridges, which may or may not be related). One way to find out would be to boot Windows, and see if it has the same problem. As I said, another way would be to reseat the connectors, to rule out mechanical problems (bad electrical connection). Another option would be to file a bug report for the PCI section of the kernel developers; maybe they have some idea.